# jQuery SimpleModal Popup: How to open second popup on first popup close event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

How to open second popup on first popup close event?

If I'm opening second modal popup on first modal popup event -

```
$divFirstPopup.modal({
    onClose: function(dialog) {
        $.modal.close();
        $.modal('#divSecondPopup');
    }
});
```

But second popup does not appear. Can anyone provide help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because:

```
$.modal('selector');
```

does not work only this should work:

```
$.modal($('selector'));
```

Comment: From a close button click event in Popup markup, I'm calling $.modal.close(); explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to open the second popup after closing the first one which takes around 2 sec. So, if you use settimeout() function and call the second pop by providing 2sec delay or greater than this. It will work. 
Since, this is not a proper way to do so. But it actually works for me.

I am using Simple modal jquery plugin:
Here is the code:

```
$('#forgot_password_modal').click(function (e) {
    $.modal.close(); // this is written to close all the popups.
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#forgot_password_form').modal({   //to open a second popup
            minHeight:570,
            minWidth:600,
            maxWidth:671,
            opacity: 90,
        onOpen: function(dialog) {
                dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function() {
                    dialog.data.hide();
                    dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function() {
                        dialog.data.slideDown('slow');

                    });
                });
            },
            onClose: function(dialog) {
                dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    dialog.container.slideUp('slow', function() {
                        dialog.overlay.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                            $.modal.close(); // must call this!
                        });
                    });
                });
            }});
    }, 2000);    
        return false;
    });
```